# Chrome extension error: Service worker registration failed. Status code: 15

Tags: javascript, json, google-chrome, manifest

My manifest JSON doesn't seem to recognize my background.js file. This is odd to me because my chrome extension worked perfectly fine a couple weeks ago. I've tried many solutions online and none fix the issue. Can anyone provide any help?

```
{
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "name": "",
  "version": "1.0",
  "description": "",
  "permissions": [
    "activeTab",
    "scripting"
  ],
  "action": {
    "default_popup": "index.html",
    }
  },
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
      "js": ["content.js"]
    }
  ],
  "background": {
    "service_worker": "background.js",
    "type": "module"
  }
}
```

```
chrome.tabs.executeScript({
  code: "window.getSelection().toString();"
}, function (selection) {
  const selectedText = selection[0];
  const resultSentence = removeStopWords(selectedText);
  document.getElementById("new-task").innerHTML = resultSentence;
```